# iOS Navigation Bar Height

Tags: ios, objective-c

novice iOS developer and I am trying to figure out why my Navigation bar height wont change after I programmatically change it. I have done the following things:

I added this piece of code to the AppDelegate.m in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 200)];
```

I was told that this would create a much larger navigation bar but it doesn't seem to be doing so. 
I have also added the following code in a specific view controller (FirstViewController.m) to change the font family, text color, etc.

```
-(void)awakeFromNib {
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(72/255.0) green:(167/255.0) blue:(192/255.0) alpha:1]];    
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:
 [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
  [UIFont fontWithName:@"CaviarDreams" size:28], NSFontAttributeName,
  [UIColor whiteColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil]];}
```

Am I doing something wrong here? 
Any help would be great!!

Answer (score 3):

You can change the height of a navigation bar if it is *your* navigation bar - if it's just a free-standing interface object.

But if you're using a UINavigationController, the height of the navigation bar is really not up to you. The UINavigationController does the layout of views, and you can't really change what it does. That is part of the price of using this built-in structure, if you see what I mean.

As for your other attempts, you are probably doing them at the wrong time. For example, in `awakeFromNib` it makes no sense to talk about `self.navigationController.navigationBar` as it is probably `nil` anyway at that time (you can easily check with logging). That is why it is better to use the appearance proxy. But then you are doing *that* too *late*; you have to use the appearance proxy in `application:didFinishLaunching...:`, because it affects only *future* instances of that type.

Basically as a newbie you need to learn *what* Cocoa lets you do and what it doesn't, and *when* are the right moments in the process to do those things. It's a big framework. You're in bed with a gorilla; you need to know when the gorilla wants to turn over and let it turn over, or you'll just get squashed. You'll get better at this as you become more accustomed to it.

Comment: Oh I see, how do I access the view from my appDelegate though?

Comment: The whole point of the appearance proxy is that you don't access any view. You use the proxy for the class! - See my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch25.html#_appearance_proxy